# Generating g(x)=2e^(-2x) in Matlab

Tags: random

I want to generate 10000 random variables with the distribution function g(x)=2e^(-2x). I'm thinking to use random but struggle to understand how to get (-2x) as part of the density function. Is random the way to go or is the another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean g(x) is the density function, not the distribution function.  What you've described is the density of an [exponential random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with rate λ=2.  You can generate these in Matlab with the [`exprnd()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exprnd.html) function.  Note that Matlab specifies things in terms of the mean `mu`, which is the inverse of the rate.  To get variates with rate 2, you specify a mean of 1/2.

Comment: Yes, it is the density function. So to generate this in matlab the line would be g=exprnd(0.5,10000,1)?

Comment: My reading of the docs is that that should give you a 10000x1 matrix of exponentials with a mean of 1/2, which means a rate of 2.